# Collapsing case statement returned data?

Tags: sql

I have a query that I created to pull yearly sales totals from an invoice table but when I run the query I get alot of 0 columns and duped row data since not every year and cust numb has sales. Here is my code.

```
SELECT * INTO #REVTEMP FROM
(
SELECT 

YEAR(CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, INVC_RDAT +5843, 0), 1)) [YEAR]
,ISNULL(b.BILLTO_NUMB,c.BILLTO_NUMB)[BILL TO NUMB]
,ISNULL(B.BILLTO_NAME, C.BILLTO_NAME) [CLIENT]
,SUM(CAST(NET_DLR AS MONEY)) [SALES REVENUE]

FROM placeholder.JR80 a
left outer join placeholder.DBO.JC10 b on b.JOB_NUMB = a.JOB_NUMB
left outer join placeholder.DBO.OE10 C ON C.ORD_NUMB = A.JOB_NUMB

 --where b.BILLTO_NUMB = 13651


 GROUP BY 
 b.BILLTO_NUMB
 ,C.BILLTO_NUMB
 ,YEAR(CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, INVC_RDAT +5843, 0), 1))
 ,B.BILLTO_NAME
 ,C.BILLTO_NAME

  --order by YEAR(CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, INVC_RDAT +5843, 0), 1))
  ) AS #REVETEMP

  SELECT 
    #REVTEMP.[BILL TO NUMB]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2006 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2006 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2007 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2007 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2008 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2008 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2009 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2009 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2010 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2010 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2011 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2011 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2012 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2012 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2013 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2013 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2014 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2014 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2015 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2015 REVENUE]
    ,CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2016 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END AS [2016 REVENUE]

    FROM #REVTEMP

  DROP TABLE #REVTEMP
```

My results look like this

```
BILL TO NUMB    2006 REVENUE    2007 REVENUE    2008 REVENUE    2009 REVENUE    2010 REVENUE    2011 REVENUE    2012 REVENUE    2013 REVENUE    2014 REVENUE    2015 REVENUE    2016 REVENUE
00022   0.00    726.28  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00022   0.00    0.00    0.00    1835.79 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00022   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    802.21  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00022   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00027   0.00    346.22  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00037   0.00    0.00    0.00    1242.78 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00037   0.00    0.00    0.00    1940.50 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00037   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    255.21  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
00123   0.00    986.20  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I would like for each cust numb to only have one rowthat contains all of their data. i think I may overthinking my process but I can't figure out how to get rid of the extra rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for you need a group by and to aggregate the case statements (sum seems like a good idea) so:

```
SELECT 
    #REVTEMP.[BILL TO NUMB]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2006 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2006 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2007 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2007 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2008 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2008 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2009 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2009 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2010 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2010 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2011 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2011 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2012 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2012 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2013 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2013 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2014 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2014 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2015 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2015 REVENUE]
    ,sum(CASE WHEN #REVTEMP.YEAR = 2016 THEN #REVTEMP.[SALES REVENUE] ELSE 0 END) AS [2016 REVENUE]
    FROM #REVTEMP
group by #REVTEMP.[BILL TO NUMB]
```